How to update the home screen in React Native Expo after logging in using a StackNavigator
I am developing my first application in React Native Expo and I have made a lot of progress but at the moment I have a problem when the user logs in and validates the data correctly but the screen does not change. Could you please help me.
This is the code of my StackNavigator
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const StackNavigator = () => {
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const checkLoginStatus = async () => {
      try {
        let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
        setIsLoggedIn(!!token);

        if (isLoggedIn) {
          setIsLoading(true);
          // Refresh your app data here (e.g., fetch user details, cart items, etc.)
          await doAsyncRefresh();
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      }
    };

    checkLoginStatus();
  }, []);

return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Inicio" component={BottomTabNavigator} options={{headerShown: false}}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Order" component={OrderScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Realiza tu pedido'
            }}
          />

          <Stack.Screen name="Detalle" component={ProductDetailScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Información del producto'
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeSreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={OrderDetailScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Historial de pedidos'
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="DatosFacturacion" component={InvoiceDataScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Datos de facturación'
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="ProductosPorCategoria" component={ShowPerCategoryListScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Productos por categoria'
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Confirmation" component={ConfirmationOrderScreen} 
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        </>
      )}
    </Stack.Navigator>
);

}
export default StackNavigator;
This is the code for my login in my AuthContext
const login = async (email, password) => {
setIsLoading(true);

try {
    
    // Send the login request to the API
    const response = await axios.post('https://ecommerce.comercializadoramya.com/api/v1/login', {
      email,
      password,
      device_name: 'Mobile'
    });

    if(response.data.success){
        const token = response.data.token;
        const user_info = response.data.user;

        await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', token);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('user_info', JSON.stringify(user_info));

        setUserInfo(user_info);
        console.log(user_info);
        console.log(token);

        await isLoggedIn(true);

    }else{
       setErrorMessage(response.data.message);
    } 

  } catch (error) {

    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      setErrorMessage('La contraseña es incorrecta por favor intenta nuevamente');
    } else if (error.response.status === 404) {
      setErrorMessage('No existe un usuario con este correo electrónico');
    } else {
      setErrorMessage('Ha ocurrido un error. Intenta nuevamente.');
    }

    // Handle error using error handling tools or custom logic
    setErrorMessage(error.message);
  }

  setIsLoading(false);

};

Assuming your AuthContext is different file? I don't see where you're updating  isLoggedIn from login function even if it's the same file. It's only being updated in the useEffect but that only runs on load and not when you login

Let me show how I managed my navigators after login.
here you need to manage two stack navigators. I am suggesting you to change your stack navigator in to two stacks. example AuthStackand AppStack
Authstack.js


    
const Authstack= ()=>{

    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  
    return(
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Login'>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login}  />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        
    );
}
export default Authstack



AppStack.js


const AppStack= ()=>{

    const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
  
    return(
        <Stack.Navigator >
            <Stack.Screen name="Inicio" component={BottomTabNavigator}   />
            <Stack.Screen name="Order" component={OrderScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Realiza tu pedido'
            }}
          />

          <Stack.Screen name="Detalle" component={ProductDetailScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Información del producto'
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeSreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={OrderDetailScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Historial de pedidos'
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="DatosFacturacion" component={InvoiceDataScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Datos de facturación'
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="ProductosPorCategoria" component={ShowPerCategoryListScreen} 
            options={{
              title: 'Productos por categoria'
            }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="Confirmation" component={ConfirmationOrderScreen} 
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        
    );
}

export default AppStack



Then You need to manage your logging using useContext hook. Context is a way to manage state globally.
Refer https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext to more information.


LoginProvider.js

    
import React,{ createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const LoginContext = createContext();

const LoginProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    useEffect(async()=>{
        const token= await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
        (token ? setIsLoggedIn(true) : setIsLoggedIn(false))
      },[])

  return (
    <LoginContext.Provider value={{isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn}}>
        {children}
    </LoginContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useLogin = () => useContext(LoginContext)


export default LoginProvider



Then you can use LoginProvider to manage your login status
Route.js


import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import AuthStack from './Authstack';
import AppStack from './Appstack';
import { useLogin } from './LoginProvider';


function Route() {

  const {isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn} = useLogin()

    return (
      <NavigationContainer  >
          {(isLoggedIn ? <AppStack/> : <AuthStack/>) }
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }

  export default Route;



I hope You can get an idea by refering above example.

Thank you for your response.
It is a very good idea that had not occurred to me to separate the browsers according to the state of the user with active session or not.
I will try what you tell me and I will be telling you thanks.
